# How to update a boolean value of an element that its inside an array of objects in react using hooks

Tags: reactjs, arraylist, react-hooks, use-state

I have the following array:

```
const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([
  {
    "idNotification": 1,
    "message": "Message number 1",
    "hideNotification": false,
  },
  {
    "idNotification": 2,
    "message": "message number 2",
    "hideNotification": false,
  }
])
```

what i want its to loop through this array to show each notification, and if I click on the X button **(the X button appear with the prop "toggle")** then i want that the notification value "hideNotification" becomes true, and therefore stop showing up on the list

```
{
   notifications?.map((tdata, index) => (
        tdata.hideNotification === false ?
            <div key={index}>
               <Alert 
                  color='primary' 
                  isOpen={!tdata.hideNotification} 
                  toggle={() => {
                     // I know this doesn´t work
                     tdata.hideNotification = true;
                  }}>
                     {tdata.message}
               </Alert>
               </div> : null
     ))
    }
```

I've seen other posts with similar question but with string values. I don't really know how to apply that to a boolean value

Comment: What is the `Alert` component? Are you using MUI5? Please give some information on what the `toggle` property of the component does.

Comment: Hi @lua_python_java, Alert its a component of reactstrap library, the toggle component allows to update the value that its on the property "isOpen"

Answer (score 0):

*Hi. Please try this:*

```
     <Alert 
        color='primary' 
        isOpen={!tdata.hideNotification} 
        toggle={() => {
          setNotifications((prevEl) => {
            let ind = prevEl.findIndex(
              (notification) => notification.idNotification === tdata.idNotification
            );
            notifications[ind].hideNotification = true;
            return [...prevEl];
          });
        }}>
            {tdata.message}
     </Alert>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, @Sardor is somewhat-correct in his answer, but he is missing explanation and also some of it is incorrect/can be simplified. I tried to edit, but the edit queue was filled.

First, @Sardor is correct in using the `setNotifications` setter in the toggle method. You do want to set the state, not the object's property value, like the OP suggests with a comment saying it didn't work. @Sardor uses the `findIndex` to get the appropriate object in the `notifications` array, but you can simply use the `tdata.idNotification` to give you the mapped ID. He also tries to edit the `notifications` state ***directly*** inside the `setNotifications` method which is incorrect.

The point of having the previous state in the params of the setter method; e.g.

```js
setNotifications((previousNotificationState) => ...)
```

is to use the previous state (at the time of running the setter) to mutate it knowing the previous state has accurate values.

---

TLDR; React makes it easy to keep track and edit the state, so don't try to make it hard. You should have a setter edit the state which would cause a re-render, here is an example:

```
{
  notifications?.map((tdata, index) => (
    hideNotification === false ?
      <div key={index}>
        <Alert 
          color='primary' 
          isOpen={!hideNotification} 
          toggle={() =>
            setNotifications((prevEl) => Array.from(prevEl)
              .map((copyTData) => copyTData.idNotification === tdata.idNotification
                ? { ...copyTData, hideNotification: true }
                : copyTData)
          )}>
            {message}
        </Alert>
      </div>
      : null
    )
  )
}
```

Notice how I:

- used `Array.from()` to copy the previous state and then mutate it

The above use of `Array.from()` to copy the state was something a well respected colleague once told me was good practice.

Last (personal) note. `index` may be a unique identifier for the `key` property, but I'd argue you almost always have something on each iteration, besides the `index`, that could be unique. In this case the `idNotification` is unique and can be used as the key instead so the `index` property doesn't clutter the mappings parameters. Indexes mean nothing in an array ***when the array changes frequently***.

Comment: stateCopy[idNotification] can't work. You need to use the index

Comment: @Topsy I disagree about using the index, but thank you for catching my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

When you want  a loop on an array and return the element and sometime not, map is not advised.

You should use filter.

You can filter your list on "hideNotification" by doing const

```
notificationsToDisplay = notifications?.filter((tdata, index) => {
 return tdata.hideNotification === false
})
```

Now you can `map` on `notificationsToDisplay` array. Since it contains only the elements having `hideNotification` property set to `true`, you'll never see the ones having the property set to false.

Also to set you hideNotification you have to use a state, you can't modify it directly using an assignation. Otherwise your component won't rerender, and you will not see any change.

You shoud use `setNotifications()`

Since you know the index or even the id of the element you want to modify you just need to find your element in the notifications array using findIndex
and then update the nofications array using `setNotifications()`

Comment: The OP was asking about how to change the property `hideNotification` when toggling. Your array only has elements with the `hideNotification` property set to false, not true. I do agree with your last paragraph, though.